# how to pass data from tableviewcontroller with custom cell to detailview

Tags: xcode, swift, tableview

I am trying to pass data from my tableviewcontroller to my detail view controller, however i am not sure how to go about doing this because i have created a custom cell, and cannot access the "cell" from outside the cellforrowatIndexPath method. Any clue as to how i would go about doing this? I am trying to pass an image, and text from a label.

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell! {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TableViewCell
    cell.userName.text = object?.valueForKey("FBName") as? String
    let userProfilePhotoURLString = object?.valueForKey("pictureURL") as? String

    var pictureURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: userProfilePhotoURLString!)!
    var urlRequest: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: pictureURL)
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (NSURLResponse response, NSData data,NSError error) -> Void in
        if error == nil && data != nil {
            cell.userImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }

    cell.ratingsView.show(rating: 4.0, text: nil)

}
    return cell
```

}

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "detailViewSegue" {
        let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
        let detailVC: DetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to declare a variable (which could be a struct for a group of data) in the DetailViewController and then fill it in the prepareForSegue.

Example:
In DetailViewController:

var xyz = ""

In the prepareForSegue:

detailVC.xyz = someArray[indexPath.row]

If using a struct in DetailViewController:

```
struct parseRecord
{
    var title = ""
    var note = ""
}
var record: parseRecord?
```

In prepareForSegue:

record?.title = title[indexPath.row]

record?.note = note[indexPath.row]

An alternative (but less desirable approach) is to use a global variable

Be aware of the need to properly apply your ? and ! to ensure that you compile.